# Replace a specific character in a string with gsub() and Regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a long length charactor vector, and some of the elements lost the word "with". I want to add it into the elements, but the elements that don't need to add the word also add it.

I used  `gsub()` function to do this and I know I need to write a approriate Regex, but I don't know how to write it.
I think the Regex should match such elements that begin with "ageup" and behind it no numbers, then replace the machted elements that contain "ageup" into "ageupwith"

```
t <- c('ageupwith65','ageup60')
gsub('ageup','ageupwith',t)
gsub('[ageup][^0-9]','ageupwith',t,fixed = T)
```

I have tried two ways but both of them are incorrectness.

Any help will be highly appreciate!

Comment: `gsub('^ageup[^0-9]','ageupwith',t)`

Comment: Well, on second thought, you might actually  be looking for `^ageup(?=\d)` - https://regex101.com/r/p6xCtq/3, right? For `ageup` that *is followed* with a digit

Comment: Thank you. But  `gsub('^ageup[^0-9]','ageupwith',t)` can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match `ageup` followed by an optional with (? means optional) and replace all that with `ageupwith` .  We have used `sub` here as there is only one match in each component but if there are several matches then use `gsub`.

```
sub("ageup(with)?", "ageupowith", t)
## [1] "ageupwith65" "ageupwith60"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a negative lookahead here:

```
t <- c('ageupwith65','ageup60')
sub('^ageup(?!\\d)', 'ageupwith', t, perl=TRUE)
```

To replace those `ageup`s that *are followed* with a digit use a *positive lookahead*:

```
sub('^ageup(?=\\d)', 'ageupwith', t, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p6xCtq/2) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p6xCtq/3).

Mind the `perl=TRUE` argument that allows using the PCRE regex engine that supports lookarounds.

The `sub` will only perform one regex replacement  upon finding the pattern:

- `^` - start of string
- `ageup` - `ageup` string
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead asserting there is no digit is found immediately to the right
- `(?=\d)` - a positive lookahead asserting there IS a digit immediately to the right of the current location.